# Where can I find a data set of graphs with known domination numbers?

Tags: graphs

I implemented an algorithm to find the minimum dominating set of a graph. I want to check the output of the algorithm against some graphs for which the domination number has been determined.

Where can I find graphs with a known domination number?

Comment: Is there another common name for dominating set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One place to look is [House of Graphs](http://hog.grinvin.org/), which is a database of "interesting" graphs. For instance, there are graphs that have been used as counterexamples to various conjectures, have extremal properties with respect to some parameter, and so on. For more, see [1].

Another possibility is using Mathematica, which also has a database of graphs accessed through its GraphData-function.

---

[1] [Brinkmann, G., Coolsaet, K., Goedgebeur, J. and Mélot, H., 2013. House of Graphs: A database of interesting graphs. Discrete Applied Mathematics, 161(1), pp.311-314.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X12002831) --- [Free version at arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.3549)