# Is there another common name for dominating set in graphs?

Tags: graphs, terminology

I am looking for graphs which the value of a minimum dominating set is known ([Where can I find a data set of graphs with known domination numbers?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/61220/where-can-i-find-a-data-set-of-graphs-with-the-number-of-dominating-set)). So far I have not found anything, so perhaps I missed a search term. Does anybody know if dominating set goes by some other name?

Comment: 1. What's a data set graph?  2. What research have you done to learn about the minimum dominating set problem?  Where have you looked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, *dominating set* is a common name, and I've never seen another name for the definition. You might get luckier if you search for *domination number* though, that's the *size* of a minimum dominating set.